# resolver lista de nombres metodo burbuja python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas tengo un trabajo que hacer de programacion en python tengo la mitad acabada pero nesesito ayuda con el metodo burbuja para que ordene una lista de nonbres alfabeticamente dada por el usuario tengo la parte de la lista preguntandole al usuario los nombres eh imprimirlos pero el motodo burbuja tengo entendido que solo sirve en nombres, una recomendacion que escuche es poner el metodo brubuja con ascii pero no entiendo como funciona ascii le pondre un ejemplo al final gracias por su ayuda:

ejemplo:

"Ponga un nombre"

Juan

Alejandro

Esmeralda

Kevin

Resultado:
"4 numeros fueron dados"

Alejandro

Esmeralda

Juan

Kevin

Comment: Agrega tu código que llevas hecho, aquí no se hacen tareas amigo =)

Comment: En Python las cadenas de caracteres son comparables y tienen una relación de orden entre ellas, así que puedes utilizar los operadores de comparación al igual que con los números. ¿Cuál es el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Es muy sencillo, solo tienes que conocer como se hace el ordenamiento en burbuja
aquí te pongo un pedazo de código que hace el ordenamiento, no se si sirva pero puedes probarlo y adaptarlo a lo que necesitas.

```
 def ordenamientoBurbuja(lista,tam):
      for i in range(1,tam):
          for j in range(0,tam-i):
              if(lista[j] > lista[j+1]):
                     k = lista[j+1]
                     lista[j+1] = lista[j]
                     lista[j] = k;
```

Como te digo, no se si funciona, lo he escrito aquí y no tengo como probarlo.